# How to find a particular solution for $y′′−y=\frac{2}{1+e^x}$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

In order to find the general solution for $y′′−y=\frac{2}{1+e^x}$,
I have to find a particular solution for $y′′−y=\frac{2}{1+e^x}$.
Any hint?

Comment: When guessing fails, you can *always* fall back on the method of variation of constants. That's something to celebrate, too: the first time you apply that method, you grow mathematically one inch taller! http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variation_of_parameters#Description_of_method

Answer (score 1):

Effective hint:

Use this method, [Variation of Parameters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variation_of_parameters). Note that $y_1(x)=e^{+x},~y_2(x)=e^{-x}$ are the solutions of the associated homogeneous OE:

$$y''-y=0$$

Answer (score 1):

You can always solve the whole thing by integrating factors.

$$(y'-y)'+y'-y=\frac2{1+e^x}$$
$$e^x(y'-y)'+e^x(y'-y)=[e^x(y'-y)]'=\frac{2e^x}{1+e^x}$$

Now integrate both sides and use integrating factors one more time.